# Can we have plinth beam below ground level for small homes?

Tags: civil-engineering

For a small 30 square meter home (8 x 3.75) is it feasible to have plinth beam 2 feet below ground? Technically, is it better than or worse off than standard procedure of plinth beam at ground level?
Also, please consider the fact that it is an earthquake prone zone.

Comment: Why do you want to build them 2 feet below ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to have the plinth beam above the ground level.

For two reasons:

You keep the floor above rain run off or subterranean water and you reduce the height of your building or the length of the columns which helps them better perform in an earthquake.